# How to Dynamically Remove Commenting from a WordPress Post

Tags: wordpress

I need to limit access to WordPress posts based on a combination of what user role they are in as well as what term is assigned to the "access-control" taxonomy of the post.

The trouble I'm running into is how to get comments to disappear from the page if the user does not have the appropriate level of access.  I don't want commenting disabled for all posts or for all users - only for specific users that don't have permission to see that post.

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'pp_disable_comments' );
function pp_disable_comments($post_object) {
     
    // only run if single page
    if (is_single()) {
         
        $pp_disable_comments = false;
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = (array) $user->roles;
         
        // skip if user is contributor/author/editor/administrator OR if the post is public
        if ((!in_array('contributor', $roles) && !in_array('contributor', $roles) && !in_array('author', $roles) && !in_array('editor', $roles) && !in_array('administrator', $roles)) || has_term('public', 'access-control')) {
             
            // run if post is tier-0 only
            if (has_term('tier-0', 'access-control')) {
                // check if user not in allowed roles
                if (!in_array('tier-0', $roles) && !in_array('tier-1', $roles) && !in_array('tier-2', $roles)) {
                    $pp_disable_comments = true;
                }
            }
 
            // run if post is tier-1 only
            if (has_term('tier-1', 'access-control')) {
                // check if user not in allowed roles
                if (!in_array('tier-1', $roles) && !in_array('tier-2')) {
                    $pp_disable_comments = true;
                }
            }
 
            // run if post is tier-2 only
            if (has_term('tier-2', 'access-control')) {
                // check if user not in allowed roles
                if (!in_array('tier-2', $roles)) {
                    $pp_disable_comments = true;
                }
            }
             
        }
         
        // disable comments if required
        if ($pp_disable_comments == true) {
            WHAT DO I PUT HERE? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
         
    }
     
}
```